# Configure SQuirreL for DB2

Tags: db2, squirrel-sql

How to configure SQuirreL for DB2 access.

In SQuirreL I do see two DB2 drivers. But they are both marked with an red X.

I checked with Start Page but did not find an easy solution :/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Download the DB2 Driver from the [IBM Website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) and extract the ZIP archive.
   Optionally you may want to copy it from the DB2 Server installation path: 
   `/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/java/db2jcc4.jar`
2. Use `db2jcc4.jar` and copy it into the squirrel folder e.g. `plugins/db2`
3. In der Driver in the tab "Extra Class Path" add the db2jcc4.jar file
4. Change the class name to `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

[image]

Comment: If you need to access remote db then url becomes `jdbc:db2://host:port/DBName`

Comment: downloading `SClients--jdbc_sqlj-11.1.2.2-FP002b`, and retrieving both the `db2jcc4.jar` and `db2jcc.jar` drivers, does not work with the class name `COM.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

Comment: I followed the answer and the comment by @Gas, only it complains for license during adding alias. For that I added 'db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar' in the extra classpath and it worked.